# Are there countries other than Russia that have their own journalistic political pranksters like Russia's Vovan and Lexus?

Tags: propaganda, journalistic-prank

In Russia we have two guys [pranksters Vovan & Lexus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSbvRXdm_Hc) nicknames. They did prank many of famous politicians: [Bush Jr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZTGlhLaqgs)., [Boris Johnson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKcPm-dDEow), the [UK defence Minister Mr Wallace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLlZnzNcSVU), or the last one [Giorgia Meloni Italian prime minister](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGIgbTUAAGQ).

So, my question: are there any other journalistic political pranksters or it is an unique Russian political "weapon"?

*i do not want to post sources at full version of the videos, because thier official You-tube channel was deleted, but you may find lots of information about them in news and ect.

And i have an egoistic interest to pranks with Putin or other Russian leaders, is it possible?)

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely on-topic but Sacha Baron Cohen etc. did this. Even as a series about America ("Who Is America?"). There's probably more.

Comment: I see. So maybe you can ask if (i.e. narrow it down to whether) there were such *politically consequential* pranks. That would surely be on-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149538/discussion-between--and-fizz).

Comment: @Giter Do you want to ask about reason of the prank? Do you think that their pranks need for discredit? i really don't know what do you asking about, make it clear please. They are not target for their own publicity, highly likely they use resurses of FSB(Russian analog FBI) and probably the intelligent. They are positioned their prank as journalistic prank. i think it is definitely clearly that they are not independent persons. But they make uncovered many interesting and provocative moments of the politic. Ofc their works can be used for anti-West propaganda in Russia, but based on truth one

Comment: I'd like to edit the title so it makes sense, but I'm not sure what is really intended.

Comment: @ohwilleke: it's probably trying to ask if there's a Western equivalent.

Comment: @ohwilleke thank you, that is it.

Comment: @Fizz [Cohen-Moore pedo test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kaJaDx51iw)

Comment: The answer to the title question is "yes" but I don't have the international popular culture expertise to cite specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

First, 'Vovan & Lexus' aren't clearly 'journalistic'. Wikipedia describes them more as comedians. Nonetheless, as Wikipedia says, in recent times they almost exclusively target foreign politicians that Russia doesn't exactly get along with. Earlier in their careers they did prank some Russian officials too.

As I suggested in a comment, Sacha Baron Cohen's show *Who Is America?* partially pranked some conservative US politicians. As Wikipedia says:

> Before *Who Is America?* aired on Showtime, some conservative public figures made statements saying that Baron Cohen had deceived them while in character.

As far as I can tell, there were no resignations as a result of his show/pranks though, but there was probably some embarrassment due to the acts that Cohen managed to make some of them do.

---

[In Italy](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-italy-politics-stunt-idUSBRE93310T20130404),  a somewhat prank call made to one of Berlusconi's would be coalition allies adviser likewise caused some embarrassment.

> Valerio Onida, one of the 10 experts in institutional and economic affairs set up by President Giorgio Napolitano, said Berlusconi was looking for protection from his legal problems and it would be better for Italians if he quit politics.
>
> Telephoned by an impersonator from Radio 24 pretending to be well-known Italian scientist Margherita Hack, Onida also said that Napolitano’s initiative was “probably useless” and was merely intended to play for time.
>
> “Berlusconi is old, let’s hope he decides to enjoy his old age and leave the Italians in peace,” said Onida, a former president of Italy’s constitutional court.
>
> “Berlusconi of course always hopes to get some advantage or protection,” Onida said, as the fake scientist prompted him for his views on the political gridlock in place since the February election.
>
> The president’s palace later issued a statement in which Onida apologized to Berlusconi and said he regretted the embarrassment that the episode might have caused to Napolitano.

I'm not entirely sure if the person 'pranked' there wouldn't have said those things if the interviewer said they were a journalist rather than a scientist, although probably they didn't expect to be on-air/on-the-record.

Also, generally speaking, journalistic ethics in many English-speaking countries prevent such methods. (They are accepted for comedy though, and there [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Political_comedy_television_series) clearly plenty of political comedy shows too.)

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting.

Comment: https://planet-randy.com/blog/en/hape-kerkelings-beatrix-wird-30/

Comment: id looked movie with Sasha Cohen - is it fun? i mean, he violate personal borders of that man. He do not prank or show up politician professional faults, but he publicly humiliates personal dignity... i am not a comedy critic, but in my country this is not counts as humor). For example: the man is a baker, i can probe his cakes how are they testy, i may prank or criticize his work, but i can't fun of his personal life and also can't to create fakes about his sexual side, while he is a baker. Cakes are separate of bees. Do not mix, do not change nouns - it is immoral. immorality is not fun.